# VBA Excel_Compare and Count : Compare cells from two sheets and make a count for lateness

Tags: excel, vba, count, compare

I have 5 students who have 2 start-time(4 start at 8am,1 starts at 11am) during the current week.

*AIM*: **Compare** the ARRIVAL TIME field for **each** student with the STARTS AT field and make a COUNT of the number of times tardy over the selected dates. The count appears in the NO OF LATENESS DURING THE WEEK field.

- I work with 1 workbook which has 2 sheets : 'Master' and 'planning_and_lateness tracker'.

`Master` sheet [master sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egk4N.jpg)

```
Student    DATE         Arrival time
Paul       2017-08-22   08:10:21
Paul       2017-08-23   08:11:52
Paul       2017-08-24   13:17:06
Lola       2017-08-22   08:04:50
Emilie     2017-08-22   08:27:54
Emilie     2017-08-23   08:50:33
Coco       2017-08-22   07:41:24
Coco       2017-08-23   07:47:17
Coco       2017-08-24   07:46:45
Jack       2017-08-22   10:00:38
Jack       2017-08-23   11:07:42
Jack       2017-08-24   11:00:27
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n7Gv.jpg)

`Planning_and_lateness tracker` sheet

[planning and lateness tracker sheet][3] <sup>no reference provided in OP</sup>

```
Staff   Starts at   No. of lateness during the week 
Paul    08:00:00    
Lola    08:00:00    
Emilie  08:00:00    
Coco    08:00:00    
Jack    11:00:00
```

The count should appear in the `No. of lateness during the week` field.

I would like to have the VBA code for it. I'm lost at sea with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no code provided - it's a "write my program for me" request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you want to use VBA for this. In my opinion, Excel is good enough. Here is what I suggest. Add 3 columns to the master data on the first sheet.

Correct Time || Week Number || Late?

Correct Time:

```
=IF(B7="Jack";TIME(11;0;0);TIME(8;0;0))
```

Week Number:

```
=WEEKNUM(C7)
```

Late?

```
=D7>E7
```

On the Second Sheet, just have a Pivot Table with this data. Week Number should be in columns, Late should be in Report filter (with Late=TRUE selected in filter), Student should be in Row Labels and Values should also contain Student Number (Count of Student Number)

You can set up the pivot table to have a dynamic source by using the offset function if you need it or you can update the source of the pivot table whenever you want to calculate.

[image: How it should look]

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner! Yup, this is what Pivot Tables were invented for!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.
Nevertheless the Master Sheet is created after running 6 macros.
The planning sheet is there by default,even though I'll be updating the STARTS AT cell values on a weekly basis since it's a roster.

Will the above answer work in that case ?
That's why I'm finding it complicated.

Thanks for your response.